# Create merge commit even if branches are identical

Tags: git

Is there a method to force create a commit even if 2 branches merging are exactly identical?
Say I have git branch A and B (while the changes made are different),
First step I merge A into B, a default commit of `Merge branch A into B` will be created (and solve conflicts if any).

Next, I want to merge branch B into A again (no merge commit will be created here), and I wish to create commit to annotate "B is now merged into A! guys!"

Comment: why do you want to do this?  seems an odd requirement (did your first merge create a merge commit? are you looking for `--no-ff` to force a merge commit?)

Comment: This is because I think this might help for team, to show a clear and visible notice that a specific branch has merged into the others, eg. my team project have branches `main_dev` , `dev01` , `dev02` , etc each number might represent different feature CR, where every feature must merge into `main_dev` before release a staging build , where staging build should only comes from `main_dev` branch let's say.

Comment: To avoid conflicts that potentially causes bugs, they always merge `maindev` into `devxx` first to resolve conflicts and issues. after make sure everything is good, lead will merge `devXX` into `main_dev` and from there onward, all changes regarding devXX should direct push into `main_dev` instead.

Comment: In case theres no conflict and clean, the lead will proceed merge `devXX` into `maindev` and no commit created here, and if any lastest fix/changes needed,  I might not aware I should push to `maindev` because the commit says `Merge maindev into devxx`

Comment: anyway this is just for my own info/knowledge. Thanks for answer/feedback

Comment: @elliotching Your process sounds akin to [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with `git merge --no-ff`, as [Anthony Sottile pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497018/create-merge-commit-even-if-branches-are-identical#comment119302535_67497018).  It's not a totally crazy thing to do, and does not create the dreaded criss-cross merge that results in complicated future recursive merges, but it is usually an odd thing to do.

Note that it depends on the idea that the hash IDs selected by your two branch names are *different hash IDs*, even if the *snapshots* match up.  Typically after merging, the snapshots *don't* match up.  The usual exception to this rule is when one of the two snapshots was itself made with `--no-ff`.

That is, we start with, e.g.:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We run `git merge br2` in this state—with commit `J` being the current commit thanks to `HEAD` being attached to name `br1` which points to `J`—and Git locates commit `L` through the name `br2`, then locates the merge base commit `H`.  The merge process compares the snapshot in `H` to the one in `J` to see what we changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

Git repeats this diff for `H`-vs-`L`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git then extracts all of `H`'s files, combines the two sets of changes, applies the *combined* changes to `H`'s files, and—if there are no conflicts—makes a new merge commit `M`, to which name `br1` points.  I tend to draw that like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

In this case, though, let's draw it this way:

```
          I--J---M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /      /
...--G--H      /
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

If we now `git checkout br2` and run `git merge` *without* `--no-ff`, Git will, as you noted in the question, do a fast-forward operation: the name `br2` will be modified to point directly to merge commit `M`.  The identity of the separate branch `br2` is lost.  That's normally fine, because we don't *need* `br2` any more at all: we can just delete it entirely, without bothering with this `git merge` step.

If we have some reason to keep the name around, though, we can do that; and if we want it to retain its identity by using a different commit *hash ID*, we need to run the merge with `--no-ff`.  We're now in this position, and we need to find commits `M` and `L` and their merge base:

```
          I--J---M   <-- br1
         /      /
...--G--H      /
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

The merge base of two commits is, loosely speaking, the "closest" commit that's on *both branches*.  Commit `L` is of course on branch `br2` as it is the tip of `br2`.  Commit `M` is only on `br1`, and its first parent `J` is only on `br1`, but its second parent `L` is on `br2`.  So commit `L` is the merge base.

The fact that the merge base `L` is the current commit is *why* this would normally be a fast-forward instead of a merge, but with `--no-ff`, Git goes ahead and runs the usual two diffs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-L> <hash-of-L>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-L> <hash-of-M>   # what they changed
```

What *we* changed is, of course, nothing at all.  So Git figures out what *they* changed—which is to say, whatever is different between `L` and `M`—and applies those changes to the files extracted from `L`.  This *snapshot* matches the snapshot in `M`, but Git goes ahead and makes new merge commit `N`:

```
          I--J---M   <-- br1
         /      / \
...--G--H      /   \
         \    /     \
          K--L-------N   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

New commits made after `M` or `N` produce, e.g.:

```
          I--J---M   <-- br1
         /      / \
...--G--H      /   \
         \    /     \
          K--L-------N--O--P   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Merging `br2` into `br1` at this point requires an explicit `--no-ff` because commit `M` is the merge base of `M` and `P`.  An attempt to merge `br1` into `br2` does nothing at all (says there is nothing to merge).  If, however, there is at least one commit on `br1` that is not on `br2` and vice versa, such as:

```
          I--J---M--O   <-- br1
         /      / \
...--G--H      /   \
         \    /     \
          K--L-------N--P   <-- br2
```

then there are commits to merge in "both directions", at least until the next merge is made (regardless of which direction we use when making it).